# Is there a more efficient way to make my ListView? Only been programming with Android for about 2 weeks

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-intent, onclick

I'm extremely new to programming android and programming in general. Haven't learnt anything previous and was just interested in learning some android dev. Anyhow I'll paste my code, but I was wondering if there's a better and more efficient way to create what I'm doing, because it took my about 3 days to even work out how to create this as I couldn't find any tutorials on setting intents up with ListView items. Thanks for your help in advance :)

public class main extends ListActivity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    String[] listitems = new String[] {"1","2","3","4","5"};

    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.rowlayout,
            R.id.label, listitems));
}
```

//This is mainly the section I'm unsure about :)

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

            switch (position){
            case 0:
                Intent second = new Intent(this, second.class);
                startActivity(second);
            }
            return;
}
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to do in onListItemClick() ? Looks like you start the "second" activity on click on the first element of the list only. If that's what you want, then the code is fine :) Otherwise, please explain what are you aiming to do there.

Comment: I'm just trying to learn how to use a ListView item to take me to a new class. What I'm doing works just fine and it IS what I'm trying to do, but I figure that maybe there is a more proficient way rather than setting a switch case for each item if there would be say 100 items in my list?
Thanks for your reply :) I'm extremely new to programming as I said and I'm just trying to learn things as proper as I can. :D

Answer (score 0):

The code is technically OK, but your onListItemClick() method implementation is somewhat unusual. A typical pattern when using ListView is to get the item you clicked on, and do something with it, or pass it to another activity. A simple example:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    // get the item we clicked on
    String item = (String) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    Intent second = new Intent(this, second.class);
    // add the clicked item to the intent, to pass it to the second activity
    second.putExtra("com.my.package.listItem", item);
    startActivity(second);
}
```

Comment: I see... So would your "String item = (String) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);" be say, comparable to where I'm saying "switch (position)"?

Would I more specifically be saying:


    String item = (String) this.getListAdapter().getItem(0);
//(.getItem(0)) as the specific position.

//Then start the new activity for position 0 here as usual?

    Intent second = new Intent(this, second.class);

Comment: Having a switch to handle clicks on list items seems like a dangerous proposition to me, if only because you're hard-coding each item's position. If you have a pre-defined set of list items, and know what to do when clicking on each item, then it would work, but then you can probably do with a simpler layout, not involving a ListView. A ListView is normally used to display dynamic data that is unknown at design time. My example above is based on that assumption.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help :) I understand what you're saying and everything :D In the short 2 weeks or so that I've been learning programming, everything 'Lists' have really been the hardest for me.

Comment: If you're just starting out with programming, looks like you're making a great progress :)

Comment: Thank's. All the progress I make is from people's tutorials that I find here and there, except for example in the cases like this where I just can't find what I'm looking for :) But like I said this whole list business is hard :P Hopefully it's one of the harder things I'll have to get passed =D

Comment: BlackRider, may I ask please what you think would be the best possible way for me to learn in detail a lot of the android coding like I've been trying? So far it's been really difficult, because it's so hard to find good tutorials with good commentaries explaining as you go what you're actually doing when learning the coding, so it makes it hard to maintain what you learn in the tutorials if you know what I'm saying :)

Comment: I think that while you're learning programming, it's best to first focus on the fundamentals. E.g. I'd do some coding in straight Java before developing for Android. Also, if you're new to programming, I'd recommend learning about the "abstract" concepts like models, views, controllers, etc, before implementing them. It's often hard to see the big picture and why are things the way the are, if you're deep in the code.

Comment: Could you possibly suggest a website or youtube channel, or better yet, maybe a torrent containing both video and written annotations, where I could learn some basic Java and all the 'abstract' concepts from? :)
Especially because I know that one of the reason I find the learning difficult, is because I haven't learn't all the concepts, but I just  don't know where to start =]

Comment: This is a great question, and I think it deserves a separate question in StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank's for all your great advice BlackRider :)
I just posted a new question on this topic, so I help people can reply with some good answers :D